# Why is nginx selecting the SSL versions & ciphers it is selecting?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have an nginx server with the following in it's configuration:

```
ssl_protocols SSLv3;
```

I'm not really able to change this *right now* (though it probably will soon). `ssl_ciphers` is not present anywhere in the config.

When Chrome connects to this server, everything works fine. However, inspecting the SSL handshake with Wireshark reveals

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 178
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 174
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 74
            Cipher Suites (37 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc026)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc02a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc002)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc00c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 59
            Extension: server_name
            Extension: elliptic_curves
            Extension: ec_point_formats
            Extension: signature_algorithms
<followed by>
    Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 4073
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
            Handshake Type: Server Hello (2)
            Length: 76
            Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
            Random
            Session ID Length: 32
            Session ID: 69e68f6d99482e742e576877c9debdd38aa1bed1a33f5067...
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
            Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 4
            Extension: server_name
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
            Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
            Length: 3985
            Certificates Length: 3982
            Certificates (3982 bytes)
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello Done
            Handshake Type: Server Hello Done (14)
            Length: 0
```

To me, it appears that TLSv1.0 got negoiated there. *How is that even possible?*
When attempting to connect with Firefox, however, more insanity ensues:

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    SSLv3 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 187
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 183
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 46
            Cipher Suites (23 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 96
            Extension: server_name
            Extension: renegotiation_info
            Extension: elliptic_curves
            Extension: ec_point_formats
            Extension: SessionTicket TLS
            Extension: next_protocol_negotiation
            Extension: status_request
            Extension: signature_algorithms
<followed by>
Secure Sockets Layer
    SSLv3 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: SSL 3.0 (0x0300)
        Length: 106
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
            Handshake Type: Server Hello (2)
            Length: 102
            Version: SSL 3.0 (0x0300)
            Random
            Session ID Length: 32
            Session ID: c985d4892896c5d553215fe3e60a2d616994ede1ed6ad715...
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
            Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 30
            Extension: server_name
            Extension: renegotiation_info
            Extension: ec_point_formats
            Extension: next_protocol_negotiation
<followed by>
Secure Sockets Layer
    SSLv3 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 2
        Alert Message
            Level: Fatal (2)
            Description: Handshake Failure (40)
```

And Firefox then displays a `ssl_error_cipher_disallowed_for_version`. Given that nginx seems to have selected SSLv3.0 but with a TLS cipher, I agree with Firefox's error, but *why did nginx do this?*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" specifically mentions "software tools commonly used by programmers" — running nginx with the goal of running a website over SSL is quite relevant to a programmer. In particular, that category seemed a closer fit than anything on ServerFault.

Comment: Nearly every program on a distribution is commonly used by a programmer. It's worthless criteria. Some claim web server configuration is on-topic if its for a developer and his developing, but I don't see any evidence of that in this question. Nginx server configurations and running it more suited for Server Fault.

Comment: @jww I see your point. The problem comes to me as a developer, not as someone operating servers day-to-day; I'm also approaching it as a developer, I feel (because that's the only way to solve it). There's [a relevant question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261541/), but the only answer is +8/-8, so seems that the community isn't sure. "To my mind, the deployment, and even the *operation* of the software we create is part of our role as developers. We should be able to discuss that on Stack Overflow." Ultimately, of course, if the community votes to move it, then it moves. :)

Answer (score 0):

More information about this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=425979